# How do you place controls on the chrome of a WPF Window when the user is on Windows XP?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-vista, windows-xp, dwm

How can you place controls on a frame of a WPF window?
 I took a look at this but I don't know how to do this in WPF. [link text](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/AeroNonClientAreaButtons.aspx)
The problem comes when The application has to run on Windows XP where there is no DWM support.
 Also, if this is running on Vista without DWM, could the article still work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article will not work, at least not exactly as written.

In order to do this on XP, you use the same basic technique, but you need to actually "draw" the chrome yourself, since the DWM doesn't exist in order to do it for you.

Comment: How would you do that in WPF though? Is it possible to do something like:

[code]
<Window .....><br>
<Window.Title><br/>
<Button> Button in window title </Button><br>
</Window.Title><br>
</Window><br>
[/code]

Comment: No.  You need to make the Window have NO title area, and draw that, manually, using WPF's drawing.  It is not trivial, unfortunately.

Comment: @AKRamkumar: "Glass transparency" is part of Aero, which is Vista+ only.  It works via the DWM.